# PyQt5 .ui file not loading

Tags: python, pyqt5

So my expected outcome is for the login.ui to show when the login button is clicked. My code reached the `def gotologin` function and the `class LoginScreen` , but it doesn't load the ui

```
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication

class WelcomeScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WelcomeScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi('welcomescreen.ui', self)
        self.login.clicked.connect(self.gotologin)

    def gotologin(self):
        login = LoginScreen()
        widget.addWidget(login)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

class LoginScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi('login.ui', self)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
welcome = WelcomeScreen()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(welcome)
widget.setFixedHeight(800)
widget.setFixedWidth(1200)
window = WelcomeScreen()
window.show()

try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print('Exiting')
```

Comment: what is `widget` inside `gotologin` method? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc the widget in the `gotologin` is declared outside the class. it is QtWidgets.QStackedWidget() . Does this clarify my question? This is my first time using PYQt5 so I don't really know if that's what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is strange since you are creating 2 WelcomeScreen: One added to the QStackedWidget and the second as a window. Besides that, the QStackedWidget has never been shown. And as the icing on the cake you don't limit the scopes of the variables.

Considering the above, it is better to create a controller that implements the logic of switching widgets and limits scopes.

```py
import sys
from functools import cached_property

from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QStackedWidget


class WelcomeScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WelcomeScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("welcomescreen.ui", self)


class LoginScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("login.ui", self)


class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.welcome)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.login)

        self.welcome.login.clicked.connect(self.goto_login)

    @cached_property
    def stacked_widget(self):
        return QStackedWidget()

    @cached_property
    def welcome(self):
        return WelcomeScreen()

    @cached_property
    def login(self):
        return LoginScreen()

    def goto_login(self):
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.login)


def main(args):
    app = QApplication(args)

    controller = Controller()
    controller.stacked_widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

And finally, do not silence the exceptions since their reason for being is to indicate that something is wrong. I prefer that when the program fails then it shouts at me that a silent error since the latter is the cause of many bugs.